# Merge two CSVs while resolving duplicates

Tags: linux, sorting, csv

I have a couple of csv's that i need to merge. I want to consider entries which have the same first and second columns as duplicates.
I know the command for this is something like

```
sort -t"," -u -k 1,1 -k 2,2 file1 file2
```

I additionally want to resolve the duplicates in such a way that the entry from the second file is chosen everytime. What is the way to do that?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? your command seems fine to me (although you could group the `-k 1,1 -k 2,2` into `-k 1,2`, I believe). The `-u` option should give you unique lines for the keys you have choosen. To have the second file prioritized, you can simply put it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the suggestion to reverse the order of files to the `sort` command doesn't work (see other answer), another way to do this would be to concatenate the files, `file2` first, and then sort them with the `-s` switch.

```
cat file2 file1 | sort -t"," -u -k 1,1 -k 2,2 -s
```

`-s` forces a stable sort, meaning that identical lines will appear in the same relative order. Since the input to `sort` has all of the lines from `file2` before `file1`, all of the duplicates in the output should come from `file2`.

The [sort man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) doesn't explicitly state that input files will be read in the order that they're supplied on the command line, so I guess it's possible that an implementation could read the files in reverse order, or alternating lines, or whatever. But if you concatenate the files first then there's no ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Change the order of the two files and add `-s`(@Jim Mischel give the hit) would solve your problem.

```
sort -t"," -u -k 1,1 -k 2,2 -s file2 file1      

man sort
   -u, --unique
          with -c, check for strict ordering; without -c, output only  the
          first of an equal run

   -s, --stable
          stabilize sort by disabling last-resort comparison
```

**Short answer**

```
awk -F"," '{out[$1$2]=$0} END {for(i in out) {print out[i]}}' file1 file2
```

**A bit long answer**:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
               FS=OFS=","; # set ',' as field separator
           }  

           {
             out[$1$2]=$0; # save the value to dict, new value would replace old value.
           } 

      END  { 
             for (i in out) {  # in the end, print all value of the dict
                 print out[i];
             }
           }' file1 file2
```

Comment: are you sure about reversing the order of files? i couldn't find it documented anywhere.

Comment: @ishan3243 change the order of files won't solve the problem. How about using `awk`, would that solve your problem?

Comment: It's possible that adding the `-s` option to the sort, in addition to reversing the order of input files, will ensure that when there's a duplicate, the item from `file2` will win.